# Use function with return value in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to use function from extern module to create date

**helper.js**

```
function createDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
  }
  if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
  }
  today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
  return today;
}

module.exports = {
  f1: createDate,
};
```

And then use it in my **server.js** in line `createdAT`:

```
let helper = require('./helper.js');

app.post('/tasks',  function(req, res) {
  let savedata;
  console.log(req.body);
    let tmpData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i ++) {
      savedata = new Model({
        'taskName': req.body[i].taskName,
        'isDone': false,
        //'createdAt': Date.now(),
        'createdAt': helper.f1(),
        'prioraty': req.body[i].prioraty
      });
      tmpData.push(savedata)
    }
    savedata = tmpData;
    Model.collection.insert(savedata, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (result) {
        res.json(result)
      }
    })
});
```

But it return me not the date in format dd/mm/yyyy but 2018-02-05T23:00:00.000Z 
The format is wrong and also the time...How could I fix this?

Comment: `createdAt` is a database field? Of what type?

Comment: The function works fine--where specifically do you actually see the date in this format? What DB mapper are you using? Does it automatically create its own `createdAt`? Unrelated, but IMO you're better off using an actual timestamp for stuff like that. Much better.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks! type was wrong, it was Date type, but I needed String

Answer (score 0):

so from what i understand you don't need the to format the date before you insert it to your database what you actually need is to format the date when you return the response. here is a little bit tweak to your code:

change `createDate()` to accept date value from database

```
function createDate(dateFromDb) {
  var today = new Date(dateFromDb);
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
  }
  if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
  }
  today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
  return today;
}
```

then uncomment the first `//'createdAt': Date.now()`

```
savedata = new Model({
    'taskName': req.body[i].taskName,
    'isDone': false,
    //'createdAt': Date.now(),
    'prioraty': req.body[i].prioraty
  });
```

then finally before you send the result do this

```
if (result) {
    result.createdAt = helper.f1(result.createdAt);
    res.json(result)
}
```